# What is the best way to synchronize data when using QQuickFramebufferObject?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtquick2

So I am using a `QQuickFramebufferObject` and `QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer` in my Qt application. As mentioned [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickframebufferobject.html#details):

> To avoid race conditions and read/write issues from two threads it is important that the renderer and the item never read or write shared variables. Communication between the item and the renderer should primarily happen via the QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer::synchronize() function.

So I have to synchronize whatever data I render when `QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer::synchronize()` is called. However, because many times the data that is sent to the render thread can be quite large I would like to avoid copying that data (which is stored in a `DataObject`), so for now I am passing a `std::shared_ptr<DataObject>` in the function and assigning that to a private member of my `QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer` class. This approaches works fine, but I am not sure if this is the "correct" way of doing things. What approach can I take in order to share/transfer the data between the GUI thread and the rendering thread?

Comment: Use a synchronization object like a mutex or a `std::atomic` to prevent writing the shared data while the render is using it.

Alternatively, use a circular buffer of structure objects and `std::atomic` variables to track the object that's ready to be rendered and the one being rendered.

You need a synchronization object because in multi-core systems there's no guarantee that a flag set one one core will be read correctly on another core without a synchronization object.  `std::atomic` is nice because you can lock individual members instead of a whole object.

Answer (score 0):

For data that is too big to copy in the synchronize() method, use a synchronization object to manage access to the data; lock it when writing, release it when finished and lock it in when rendering and access the data directly. You are safe as long as only one thread is accessing the data at a time.

The risk of skipped frames increases the longer the synchronization object is locked. Locking for writing longer than half the optimal render quantum (8.5ms = ~16.7ms/2) will incur dropped frames, but you probably have much more happening in your app so the real number is lower.

Alternatively, you could use a circular buffer for your large data structures with a protected index variable so you can simultaneously write to one structure while reading from another. Increment the index variable when all data is ready to display and call QQuickItem::update().